# version 5 react router dom page navigator using useHistory not navigating

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have using react-router-dom version 5.2.0

```
import { NavLink, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

export const Login = () => {
  const history = useHistory();

  const userLogin = async () => {
    const userResponse = await userLoginService(eMail, password);
    console.log(userResponse.userResponse);
    if (userResponse.userResponse.data) {
      toast.success("You have successfully logged in");
      history.push("/dashboard");
    } else {
      toast.error(userResponse.userResponse.error);
    }
  };
}
```

Below is my login button `onClick` code

```
<button className="btn mt-3 loginText" onClick={userLogin}>
  Login
</button>
```

When I click login button API call went to backend and once after getting response I will navigate to dashboard screen, but it's not working...

If I use `history.push` in top of the function it worked but if I navigate based on response it has not navigating...

Comment: I don't see any overt issue with this code. Think you could try creating a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces this issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: edited my code with declaration of useHistory

Answer (score 0):

You need to call useHistory first like this

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

function HomeButton() {
  let history = useHistory();

  function handleClick() {
    history.push("/home");
  }

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
      Go home
    </button>
  );
}
```

src: https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks

Comment: yes i have did the same.  but not navigating... if i navigate history.push("/dashboard"); based on condition it's not navigating

Answer (score 0):

You try use `useNavigate`

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
const navigate = useNavigate();

const redirectToHome = () =>  {
   navigate("/home")
}
return (
  <button type="button" onClick={redirectToHome}>
    Home
  </button>
);
```

Comment: OP is using `react-router-dom@5` so `useHistory` is the correct hook. `useNavigate` is a v6 hook.

Comment: what @DrewReese told is right.....